# Starting Memurai Server on windows 10

Tags: database, redis, memurai

C:\Program Files\Memurai>memurai-server
'memurai-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I tried restarting my memurai server after running the shutdown command to shutdown memurai. Can somoene please direct me

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it as a service you can always start it up from Services or run "net start ".
You should also go through the documentation here: https://docs.memurai.com/en/windows-service and you'll find more about how to do this.